# How do flight attendants know seat belts are fastened?

Tags: safety, flight-attendant

I'm a simple curious traveller. I always see flight attendants passing by the seats checking whether belts are fastened. They pass quickly and without looking carefully at each single person, to see if the seat belt is fastened.

I stared at them and found them looking at some specific point on the ground that could possibly tell them with a glance, but I couldn't figure out what was that point.

Can somebody explain how do they check the seat belts status?

Comment: Today I learned that the in-flight safety belt check is referred to as "[The Crotch Watch](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2015/12/22/flight-attendant-slang_n_6329064.html)" and the "[Groin Scan](https://www.dauntlessjaunter.com/2014/06/25/airline-lingo-and-slang/)"

Comment: You can perceive a lot in your peripheral vision. A quick glance can be enough to see that the buckle is in place.

Comment: They look at hundreds of seat belts per day, eventually you get good enough that a "passing glance" is sufficient to decide if it is buckled properly or not.

Comment: @ratchetfreak I noticed in many times, the buckle is hidden from the steward vision (hands, book, tablet, etc.) and they still can know if it is fasten or not.

Comment: @RonBeyer if it is really with just direct eye vision, then it is really amazing.

Comment: This is another question with the answer "MkII eyeballs" (That's the upgrade from MkI eyeballs, with more specific training in what they're looking for)

Comment: @NadjibMami they cannot possibly know if it's buckled if the buckle is completely obscured from vision. If they're doing proper checks they will stop and ask you to show them that your buckle is done correctly if they cannot see it.

Comment: X-ray vision :D

Comment: Funny :) - Having some technical support was my intuition (which is technically feasible). But yea, maybe "they are not properly checking" is the easiest answer.

Comment: Found this relevant question: https://www.quora.com/In-aircrafts-why-is-there-no-indicator-to-say-whether-seat-belt-is-fastened-or-not-for-every-seat

Comment: They're also checking for tray tables and debris (eg bags) on the ground that would be dangerous in a dark/smokey plane with people panicking trying to get off, hence the looking at the ground and catching your belt status in peripheral vision.

Comment: The truth is they can't "know" without checking your seat belt and buckle individually, which they typically don't have the time or interest to do unless they suspect something. It's not difficult to pull the seat belt snugly across your lap and tuck the buckle under your butt cheek and make it look like you're 'securely fastened', at least if you're not in an aisle seat. But there's no excuse for planes not to have had mechanical detection for this (just like cars) for the last 30 years or so; airlines are just cheap.

Comment: @TylerH thanks for the addition. Someone suggested that belt-fastening should nowadays become a common sense, so every traveler *should* automatically think of fastening their seatbelt while seated. They are further reminded during the flight by the attendants and the signal on top of their heads, so a human check is after all not even necessary (anymore). Regardless of how reasonable is this thesis (you mentioned that such a system is already well integrated into cars), I think a small mechanical check would still be a viable addition that could potentially prevent troubles.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Flight attendants check that seatbelts are fastened the old fashioned way - by looking and confirming each passenger has correctly fastened them. There is no indicator anywhere around each seat which indicates as such.

If the attendants is doing this "..quickly and without looking carefully at each single person" then they are [possibly] not doing their job correctly. That they can do it swiftly, is *not* the same thing; like all things if you practice it every day you can do it "quickly and efficiently" without compromising safety.

Comment: More than 2 years later and after travelling several times more, I ensure that some attendants are not really ensuring everyone's belt is fastened. I saw belt-unfastened seats being passed past without notice, even though visibly checked.

Answer (score 10):

In addition to Jamiec's correct answer, I would add that you can tell when a seat belt is not fastened even if the buckle is covered by someone's shirt (or belly!).  You can normally see the segment of belt alongside the person's hip and it's easy to tell if that piece of strap is under tension or not.  Some people actually try to disguise the fact that their seat belt isn't fastened by covering up the buckle, hoping to avoid detection.  By looking for the strap alongside their hip, I can avoid asking to see the buckle itself.

Of course, if I can't really tell by a quick glance, I ask them to show it to me.  It's very rare that anyone actually takes offense to this.

Comment: Thanks for the useful addition. Maybe one day my imagined solution for a guaranteed check will be implemented :)

Comment: @NadjibMami even if the seat belt check could be automated, there are additional things the flight attendants need to check.  Baggage stowed, seats upright, tray tables, phones stowed, etc.  A walk through the cabin would still be necessary.

Comment: Sure, that passage is still important, it makes the flight more convivial to my opinion. Only the careful seat belt check would be saved.